# getMesh from gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, service, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

We are interested in retrieving the vertex and triangles from a loaded model directly out of gazebo (without loading the mesh from a file separately). In fact, we need to get the meshdata knowing the GeomID (for instance the GeomIDs that are in contact).

What we did is to start a simple_world.launch and run a basic package to access the model data. Here is the code :

```
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
            ros::init(argc,argv,"gazebo_ros_getmesh",ros::init_options::NoSigintHandler);
    
            std::vector<gazebo::Model*> models;
            models = gazebo::World::Instance()->GetModels();
            if(models.size()>0)
                    ROS_INFO("ModelName:%s",models[0]->GetName().c_str());
            else
                    ROS_INFO("NoModel");
     }
```

We always get "NoModel".
We thought it would be possible to access to the meshdata via some service that retrieves first the models (gazebo::World::Instance()->GetModels() ) and then the Body, Geom and finally the meshdata.

Appears to us, that any call to such functions must be done in gazeboros node but cannot be called from an external package of our own.

Is there another mean to access to the Meshdata ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11445/getmesh-from-gazebo/) by [GuiHome](https://answers.ros.org/users/768/guihome/) on ROS Answers with karma: 242 on 2011-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We finally found our way through this, by creating a gazebo_plugin and attaching it to the world to get access to the models->body->geom->ogrevisual->mesh

this helped us a lot :
http://answers.ros.org/question/1919/gazebo-tutorials-for-creating-a-plugin

Any other simpler mean to access to the triangles of the mesh (not the geoms) that are in contact during a collision would be appreciated.

---

Originally posted by [GuiHome](https://answers.ros.org/users/768/guihome/) with karma: 242 on 2011-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CR7](https://answers.ros.org/users/56014/cr7/) on 2020-06-22**:
Can you please help me with the plugin. unable to proceed after fetching the models.